# Grab collor information from PNG file

Tags: java, c++, png

If you are able to view the bytes of a png file, how could you grab color information. How do you know which bytes are red, blue, or green. Is there any way to extract color information when looking at the bytes of png file?

What would be the process for extracting pixel colors using C++ or Java?

Comment: 1. No. The *image* part of a raw PNG ate compressed, and "viewing the bytes of a png file" will show the compressed data. 2. Library recommendations are subjective, and prone to changes.

Answer (score 1):

in Java you can do something like this

```
public static Color[][]  byteArrayToColors(byte[] bytes){  
        BufferedImage paintImage=null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            paintImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
         Color[][] cols = new Color[paintImage.getWidth()][paintImage.getHeight()];
    for(int z = 0;z < paintImage.getWidth();z++){
        for(int a = 0;a < paintImage.getHeight();a++){
            int color = paintImage.getRGB(z, a);

            int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            int alpha = (color>>24) & 0xff;
            Color col = new Color(red,green,blue,alpha);
            cols[z][a] = col;

        }
    }
return cols;
}
```